# Commands Grouping

Tags: command, syntax

I understand the ampersand `&` at the end of a command sequence executes it on the background (in "parallel"), the semicolon `;` allows for sequential (in "series"), and the parenthesis allows [command grouping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244380/shell-combine-semicolon-and-ampersand-in-bash-sh).

Suppose I have a `bash` file with some commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd1
cmd2
cmd3
cmd4
```

If i want to apply command grouping, for example, execute the first two in paralell, wait, then execute the next two in parallel, i should put?:

```
#!/bin/bash
( \
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
); \
( \
cmd3 &
cmd4 & 
)
```

or everything must be mandatory in a single line?

```
#!/bin/bash
(cmd1 & cmd2 &);(cmd3 & cmd4 &)
```

or using the continue line character everywhere?

```
#!/bin/bash
( \
cmd1 & \
cmd2 &); \
( \
cmd3 & \
cmd4 & )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply use `&` and `wait`

```
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
wait
cmd3 &
cmd4 &
wait
```

wait will wait for backgroup process.

as for line continuation, just use `(` and `)`, note this is usefull only if you have redirection.

```
(
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
wait
) > some-log.A
(
cmd3 &
cmd4 &
wait
) > some-log.B
```

note that without `wait`, subshell will return immediatly.

```
date ; (
> sleep 20 &
> sleep 10 &
> ) ; date
Wed Nov 29 16:08:15 CET 2017
Wed Nov 29 16:08:15 CET 2017
```

compared to

```
date ; (
> sleep 20 &
> sleep 10 &
> wait
> ) ; date
Wed Nov 29 16:10:08 CET 2017
Wed Nov 29 16:10:28 CET 2017
```